# Mock return on a static extension method in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

How do I force a mocked return on a static extension method in Kotlin?

I have a data class called `Job`

```
data class Job(
    val id: ObjectId) {
}
```

and a `Mapper` object with an extension method that's static for the `Job` class.

```
object Mapper {
    Job.toOtherJob(): OtherJob.Job {
    // Do work
    }
}
```

The issue is that `toOtherJob` method calls the real one, and I cannot force a doReturn on it.

Test class

```
class ServiceTests {
    @Mock
    private val job: Job? = null

    @BeforeAll
    fun setUp() {
        // Initialize mocks.
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
    }

    @AfterAll
    fun cleanUp() {
        // Cleanup mocks.
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this).close()
    }

    fun testJob() {
        val otherJob = OtherJob()

        whenever(job.toOtherJob()).thenReturn(otherJob)

        // Act
        job.toOtherJob() // <- This calls the real method, does not get mocked.
    }
}
```